# Trying to make a photo site in HTML/CSS, however I can't figure out how/why my pictures are in a straight line instead of rows

Tags: html, css

```css
  img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

gallery {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery figure {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #4c1b1b;
  border-top: solid 1px #4c1b1b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .left,
  .main,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Owen Mullins - Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="selfie.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="selfie_tablet.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 1000px)">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Owen Mullins - Gallery</h1>
      <h2>Photo Gallery</h2>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="education.html">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <div class="gallery">
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo8.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo8_thumb.jpg" alt="Photo Shoot">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Photo Shoot</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo1.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo1_thumb.jpg" alt="Guadalupe River">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Guadalupe River</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo2.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo2_thumb.jpg" alt="San Antonio River">
          </a>
          <figcaption>San Antonio River</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo3.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo3_thumb.jpg" alt="Cowboy">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Mommas don't let your babies grow up to be cowboys</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo4.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo4_thumb.jpg" alt="Amacoalola">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Amacoalola Falls</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo5.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo5_thumb.jpg" alt="Enchanted Rock">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Enchanted Rock</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo6.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo6_thumb.jpg" alt="River Shot">
          </a>
          <figcaption>River Shots</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo7.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo7_thumb.jpg" alt="Dinker Bass">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Dinker Bass</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Copyright &copy; 2023, Owen Mullins<br><br>
      <b>Email:</b>
      <a href="mailto:omullins@augusta.edu">omullins@augusta.edu</a>
      <br>
      <b>Social Media:</b>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/owenmullins_/" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/owen.mullins.180" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: photo of output when browser is popped out or full screened]

I am a student taking an HTML class so my knowledge is very limited. If this is a stupid question please be kind, I hope I've provided enough information for someone to answer this, but If I wanted the photos to "flow" naturally and descend down the screen into a new row, what would I have to do? Is this a CSS fix or HTML? Thank you, I would be happy to provide the HTML code as well if this is not enough.

I was trying to wrap the photos into neat rows dependent on the size of the browser/photo. The site looks fine when it's in a minimized view or portrait mode, but when completely popped out into a browser viewing mode it reverts to a plain horizontal flow.

Comment: Please include your HTML code so we can have a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just as a heads up, you included you personal e-mail/socials in your post, which is maybe not the best idea (but up to you!).  Besides this, I don't fully understand the question.  Are you just wanting your pictures to wrap onto new lines?  Is the image in your post the current, non-desirable state, or the goal state?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the display:inline-block; property from the .gallery figure tag like this:

```css
  img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

gallery {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery figure {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #4c1b1b;
  border-top: solid 1px #4c1b1b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .left,
  .main,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Owen Mullins - Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="selfie.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="selfie_tablet.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 1000px)">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Owen Mullins - Gallery</h1>
      <h2>Photo Gallery</h2>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="education.html">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <div class="gallery">
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo8.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo8_thumb.jpg" alt="Photo Shoot">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Photo Shoot</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo1.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo1_thumb.jpg" alt="Guadalupe River">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Guadalupe River</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo2.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo2_thumb.jpg" alt="San Antonio River">
          </a>
          <figcaption>San Antonio River</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo3.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo3_thumb.jpg" alt="Cowboy">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Mommas don't let your babies grow up to be cowboys</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo4.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo4_thumb.jpg" alt="Amacoalola">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Amacoalola Falls</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo5.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo5_thumb.jpg" alt="Enchanted Rock">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Enchanted Rock</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo6.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo6_thumb.jpg" alt="River Shot">
          </a>
          <figcaption>River Shots</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="photos/photo7.jpg">
            <img src="photos/photo7_thumb.jpg" alt="Dinker Bass">
          </a>
          <figcaption>Dinker Bass</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Copyright &copy; 2023, Owen Mullins<br><br>
      <b>Email:</b>
      <a href="mailto:omullins@augusta.edu">omullins@augusta.edu</a>
      <br>
      <b>Social Media:</b>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/owenmullins_/" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/owen.mullins.180" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```